# Probability of an event that can trigger off itself

Tags: probability

Scenario 1: You have 10 coins, and a very simple slot machine. You insert 1 coin, pull the lever, and you get 100 tickets. In this scenario, your expected outcome is 1000 tickets.

Scenario 2: Same as Scenario 1, but whenever you insert a coin and pull the lever, there is a 10% chance the next lever pull is free. In this scenario, with 10 coins, you should expect 1/10 level pulls to grant you a free level pull, which will also give 100 tickets, so your expected outcome is 1100 tickets.

Scenario 3: Same as Scenario 2, however, a free lever pull also has a 10% chance of granting another free lever pull.

**What is the expected outcome in tickets of Scenario 3? How do you calculate this "stacking" probability?**

I can see it being something like 1+(10/100)+(10/1000)+(10/10000)...which I'm expecting to be 1.111 repeating, or 10/9, with an expected outcome of 1111 tickets. Even if that's the answer, is there a proof/rule to back up my intuition?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave another answer before, but there's a much simpler proof.

The expected number of lever pulls $E$ can be written as:

$E = (1+E) \cdot p + 1\cdot(1-p)$

where $p$ is the probability of pulling the lever again. If we don't pull the lever, we end up with $1$ pull. If we pull the lever, then we have $1$ pull, but everything recurses again, so we have $1+E$ pulls.

Solving for $E$, we get $E=\frac {1}{1-p}$ which is $\frac {10}9$ when $p=\frac 1{10}$

Answer (score 0):

The **expected** number of lever pulls with one coin is:

$E=1\cdot P(1)+2\cdot P(2)+3\cdot P(3)+ \dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot P(n)$

Where $P(n)$, the probability of pulling the lever $n$ times, is $(\frac {1}{10})^{n-1}\cdot\frac {9}{10}$

The $\frac {9}{10}$ occurs when you don't get another free pull, terminating the run. You can multiply the $\frac {1}{10}$ together because the probability of getting another free level pull is **independent** of the past results.

This gives us $E=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9n}{10^n} = 9\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{10^n} =9\cdot(\frac {1}{10}+\frac{2}{100}+\frac{3}{1000}+\dots)$

This is an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence), which turns out to be $9\cdot \frac{10}{81}=\frac{10}{9}$ as your intuition suggested.